# Docker cloudstor:aws volume not migrating its contents between instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

We have AWS EC2 cluster running Docker on Swarm mode.

We are deploying our services using a compose file, and we have data related services bound to volumes with persistent content, as a database for instance.

Since Docker Swarm does service discovery and load balance automatically, and we tend to avoid instance affinity as a good practice, we need our volumes to be automatically migrated along with our data related services.

We tried to use [cloudstor:aws](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/persistent-data-volumes/) plugin to achieve that.

Our actual problem is that our volumes don't move along with our services when they get reallocated.

This is our configuration on our compose file:

```
version: '3.3'

volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: "cloudstor:aws"
    driver_opts:
      size: "20"
      ebstype: "gp2"
      backing: "relocatable"

services:
    db:
      image: postgres:9.3-alpine
      volumes:
        - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: Hi! Are your docker swarm services deployed on more that one AWS Availability Zone?

Comment: No, they are all deployed at sa-east-1

Comment: Ok, then did you already set and attach IAM permissions to the ec2 (permissions that allow cloudstor create / move ebs volumes) @see https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/iam-permissions/ ? If yes, could you then check dockerd daemon's logs and share them in your question?

Comment: Hello @FrançoisMaturel, ty for the fast response. I am using Docker for AWS CloudFormation template ( https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/ ), so I believe its very well integrated, Looking at logs I see lots of debug info, but nothing relevant, I don't know which part I should post here, are you looking for anything in specific?